# How to test time dependent methods with PEST PHP

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, php-pest

In my laravel/filament app, I have a function that takes in a database record and uses the `id`, `created_at` and list of previous records to transform the id from `6` to `2023-006`, it also resets the counter in a new year. so if the record with id `10` was the first record in 2024, the id will be `2024-001` rather than `2024-10`.

I want to test this function using pest and make sure the counter reset at new year actually works, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Carbon::setTestNow()